# unorderable type error in module python-axolotl-curve25519.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, yowsup

I wanted to install the module python-axolotl-curve25519.py but I keep getting an unorderable type error .`TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()`.
I have tried it on python 3.4 and python 2.7. but I keep getting the same error from both pip and easy_install. I want to install yowsup library.

This was the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wzoc4cv_\python-axolotl-
curve25519\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
        platforms='any'
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 6
1, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 554, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line
 50, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 317, in run
        force=self.force)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
        return klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__

        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__

        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kenny\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-wzoc4cv_\\py
thon-axolotl-curve25519\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(
__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\
Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-c9d9a1jq-record\install-record.txt --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

    running build

    running build_ext

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wzoc4cv_\python-axolotl-
curve25519\setup.py", line 27, in <module>

        platforms='any'

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 6
1, in run

        return orig.install.run(self)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 554, in run

        self.run_command('build')

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run

        self.run_command(cmd_name)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line
 50, in run

        _build_ext.run(self)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 317, in run

        force=self.force)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler

        return klass(None, dry_run, force)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__


        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)

      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 126, in __init__


        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":

    TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()

    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the traceback.  What line of what module is giving the error?

Comment: sorry. I totally forgot. I tried installing it on python 2.7 and it worked fine.